# How to add a filter that triggers calculation in a plot

Tags: plot, interactive

I would like to plot an interactive graph that allow users to use a few down down lists to select the desired data to display.

For example, I want to plot the following data

| State | Product | Month | Converted customers | Potential customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | Blue | Jan | 5 | 20 |
| CA | Blue | Feb | 10 | 20 |
| CA | Red | Jan | 8 | 15 |
| CA | Red | Feb | 10 | 25 |
| NY | Blue | Jan | 15 | 10 |
| NY | Blue | Feb | 10 | 20 |
| NY | Red | Jan | 25 | 20 |
| NY | Red | Feb | 30 | 40 |

The graph will plot conversion rate = converted customers / potential customers by month.
There will be 2 drop down lists in the graph: State and Product

If user selects CA, the graph would plot Jan: (5+8)/(20+15) Feb: (10+10)/(20+25)
If user selects CA and Blue, the graph would plot Jan: 5/20 Feb: 8/15

The main thing is that I want the graph to auto-calculates every time users change their selection in the drop down.

I'm able to this is Excel with Pivot tables and Slicers, but wasn't sure how I would do this in Python.